# My react Material UI buttons aren't rendering

Tags: reactjs, button, material-ui, render, visible

I've written the same code everywhere but it doesn't render my buttons. It does render but is not visible. The button are present between the logo and the search input.

There aren't any errors nor build fail to debug the problem.

I tried copying and pasting the code from the second too!
[image]

```
import React from "react";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
import { Box, Container, ThemeProvider, Input, useScrollTrigger, Slide, AppBar, Toolbar } from '@mui/material'
import { Button } from "@mui/material";
import customTheme from "./Theme"

function HideOnScroll(props) {
    const { children, window } = props;
    const trigger = useScrollTrigger({
        target: window ? window() : undefined,
    });
  
    return (
        <Slide appear={false} direction="down" in={!trigger}>
            {children}
        </Slide>
    );
}

const ariaLabel = { 'aria-label': 'description' };

function Navigation(props) {
  return (
    <Container>
        <ThemeProvider theme={ customTheme }>
            <HideOnScroll>
                <AppBar color={"primary"}>
                    <Toolbar>
                        <Box m={1} p={1}>
                            <Link to=""><img src="/static/brand-logo.svg" alt="brand-logo" /></Link>
                        </Box>
                        <Box m={1} p={1}>
                            <Button variant="outlined" style={{ borderRadius: 20 }} href="/">Home</Button>
                            <Button variant="outlined" style={{ borderRadius: 20 }} href="/blog">Blogs</Button>
                            <Button variant="outlined" style={{ borderRadius: 20 }} href="/create-blog">Create</Button>
                        </Box>
                        <Box m={1} p={1}>
                            <Input color={"secondary"} placeholder="Can't search :)" inputProps={ariaLabel} />
                        </Box>
                    </Toolbar>
                </AppBar>
            </HideOnScroll>
            <Toolbar />
        </ThemeProvider>
    </Container>
  );
}

export default Navigation;
```

Another button code **which works**

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid, Divider, Typography, Button } from "@mui/material";
import InstagramIcon from '@mui/icons-material/Instagram';
import LinkedInIcon from '@mui/icons-material/LinkedIn';
import GitHubIcon from '@mui/icons-material/GitHub';

export default function Home(props) {
    return(
        <Grid container spacing={4} justifyContent="center" alignItems="center" color={"primary"}>
            <Grid item xs={12} sm={6} lg={4}>
                <Typography variant="h1" component="div" gutterBottom>A painting of my life.</Typography>
                <Button size="large" variant="outlined" style={{ borderRadius: 50, fontSize: 40 }} href="/blog">Peek My Diary</Button>
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

Comment: I think you should check your buttons' CSS in your browser console, what does it yield?